# resize and align SVG in flexbox

Tags: css, svg

I try to create a flexbox which has a SVG as a child.
The svg should be as large as possible in width and height.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 2fr 2fr;
  gap: 1em;
}

.parent {
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;  
  background: lightgrey;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.box {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

svg {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">

  <div class="parent">
    <div>no box around SVG</div>
    <div>SVG height larger then width</div>
    <svg viewBox="0 0 1 3">
      <path d="M0 0 L1 3 L0 3" />
    </svg>
    <div>SVG has maximum height</div>
    <div>and centers horizontal</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="parent">
    <div>no box around SVG</div>
    <div>SVG width same as height</div>
    <svg viewBox="0 0 1 1">
      <path d="M0 0 L1 1 L0 1" />
    </svg>
    <div>SVG has maximum height</div>
    <div>and centers horizontal</div>
  </div>

  <div class="parent">
    <div>no box around SVG</div>
    <div>SVG width larger than height</div>
    <svg viewBox="0 0 3 1">
      <path d="M0 0 L3 1 L0 1" />
    </svg>
    <div>SVG has maximum width</div>
    <div>and centers vertical</div>
  </div>
  
  
  <div class="parent">
    <div>box around SVG</div>
    <div>SVG height larger than width</div>
    <div class="box">
      <svg viewBox="0 0 1 3">
        <path d="M0 0 L1 3 L0 3" />
      </svg>
    </div>
    <div>SVG has maximum height and width</div>
    <div>but should be same as box 1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="parent">
    <div>box around SVG</div>
    <div>SVG width same as height</div>
    <div class="box">
      <svg viewBox="0 0 1 1">
        <path d="M0 0 L1 1 L0 1" />
      </svg>
    </div>
    <div>SVG has maximum height and width</div>
    <div>but should be same as box 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="parent">
    <div>box around SVG</div>
    <div>SVG width larger than height</div>
    <div class="box">
      <svg viewBox="0 0 3 1">
        <path d="M0 0 L3 1 L0 1" />
      </svg>
    </div>
    <div>SVG has maximum width</div>
    <div>and is centered vertical like box 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The first 3 boxes are working, but why aren't the last 3 boxes work like the first 3 boxes? There is just another flexbox in between. How to get the last boxes working?

It seems like the last 3 boxes are always using the full width.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for Firefox:
I don't know why but it works if I put `height="1" or width="1"` or any other value to the svg and add `svg {height: auto; width: auto;}` to overwrite the html attributes.

Solution for Chrome and Firefox:
I have to add both `height="1" width="1"` to svg and just add `svg {width: auto;}`

But I can not explain why.